# How to make browser cache assets with express.js

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers, http-caching

I want my assets to be cached by browser. So I use:

```
var oneDay = 86400000;
app.use(express.static('public', { maxAge: oneDay }));
```

So in response I see:

```
cache-control: public, max-age=86400000
```

But when assets are requested by browser it still makes request to server and usually gets 304 not modified response and only then takes version from cache.

**In response I also see 'Etag' and 'Last-Modified' headers, maybe they for such behaviour? (any why I wasn't able to get read of Last-Modified header to check it.**

If I understand correctly I max-age was set in response when downloading resource for the first time, then browser while the period (set by max-age) should take if from cache and not make any request to server.

What am I doing wrong?

I wonder how people serve static assets and index files in production with express.js?

Comment: I think I need less radical solution for now.